# What's the real meaning of this part of a poem?

Tags: meaning

It is a part of a poem by Ntozake Shange.

> i live in music
>   live in it
>   wash in it
>   i cd even smell it
>   wear sound on my fingers
>   sound falls so fulla music
>   ya cd make a river where yr arm is &
>   hold yrself
>   hold yrself in a music

What is the meaning of "I cd"?

Thank you

Comment: Not sure I agree with the close votes - this isn't one of those "find the deeper meaning of the poem" questions.

Answer (score 6):

It's worth noting that the questioner has accurately transcribed the unusual spelling of the poem *i live in music*. Ntozake Shange is an established poet, who has deliberately spelled this way, for this poem.

"i cd even smell it" is clearly a deliberate misspelling of "I could even smell it".